# How to show all category items of menu in magento2

Tags: php, html, magento2

[My phtml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxiTo.png). [block file code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71ssS.png). [all menu category data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTO8V.png).[output when I show data without using recursion upto two child category levels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8Zyp.png). [output when I try to use recursion to show all child categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6g8r.png)

Actually I need to create mega menu in magento 2. So I got navigation category data using collection in my module block file then on my module phtml.
  Now I am want to display navigation category label names using recusive foreach loop. But it is not working. when i am not using recursion it is showing,
  but when I use recusive function or array funtion array walk, It is not working. I need to use recursion so that it shows label name of all child categories. 
  Please help. 
  I have have added imges of my block file code, Phtml file, and module frontend output please help. why recursion is not working?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is

when you don't use recursion, you get the right structure of result array ( categories ).

Otherwise, you get the wrong structure.

I think you can var_dump the array to see the structure in both of cases then compare them.

If you are a developer then you can use debugging to see the structure of the array.